LWC @wire getRecord getFieldValue value not available for filter on getPicklistValues
My LWC displays a custom path but requires a filter on a value in the data as to which of the picklist values to display. With help on my previous post to get the filtering to work (LWC custom path requires conditional loading of stages) I now have another problem in that it is not picking up the field value until after it's done the picklist value code.
How would I ensure that it first gets the field value and then only does the picklist filtering?
        import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from "lwc";
        import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
        import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
        import { getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
        import REGISTRY_TRANSFER from "@salesforce/schema/RegistryTransfer__c";
        import REGISTRY_TRANSFER_SETTLEMENT_STATUS from "@salesforce/schema/RegistryTransfer__c.Settlement_Status__c";
        import ISSUE_CONTRACT_ACCEPTANCE from "@salesforce/schema/RegistryTransfer__c.Issue__r.Contract_Acceptance__c";
        const FIELDS = [ISSUE_CONTRACT_ACCEPTANCE];

        export default class RegistryTransferPath extends LightningElement {
        @api objectApiName;
        @api recordId;
        stageOptions;
        settlementStatus;
        @track record;
        @track acceptance;

        currentStep = "slds-path__item slds-is-current";
        completeStep = "slds-path__item slds-is-active";
        incompleteStep = "slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete";

        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS })
        wiredRT({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
          console.log(
            "registryTransferPath @wire getRecord recordId: ",
            this.recordId
          );
          this.record = data;
          this.acceptance = getFieldValue(this.record, ISSUE_CONTRACT_ACCEPTANCE);
          this.error = undefined;
          console.log("@wire this.acceptance: " + this.acceptance);
            } else if (error) {
              this.error = error;
              console.log("error: " + error);
              this.record = undefined;
            }
        }

        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: REGISTRY_TRANSFER })
        registryTransfer;

        @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$registryTransfer.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: REGISTRY_TRANSFER_SETTLEMENT_STATUS
        })
        picklistValues({ data }) {
            if (data) {
              let increment = 1;
              console.log("getPicklistValues this.acceptance: " + this.acceptance);
              const isAcceptanceEnabled =
                this.acceptance === "Enabled" ||
                this.acceptance === undefined ||
                this.acceptance === null;
              console.log("isAcceptanceEnabled: " + isAcceptanceEnabled);
              this.stageOptions = data.values
                .filter(
                  (item) =>
                    isAcceptanceEnabled ||
                    (item.value !== "Awaiting Approval" &&
                      item.value !== "Contract Acceptance")
                )
                .map((item) => {
                  return {
                    position: increment++,
                    value: item.value,
                    pathStatus: this.incompleteStep,
                    tickIcon: false
                  };
                });
            }
        }

When I run it with dev tools enabled this is the result I see.


In order to build stageOptions you need the result of both getRecord and getPicklistValues wire adapter. The issue is that they run in parallel and there is no way to guarantee that one of them will always end before the other one.
To workaround this, you could use specific instance properties set in each wired function as flag and extract the code you want to run after them both in a new method that will use those flags as guard, finally you'll call that new method at the end of both wired functions.
The flag for getRecord could be this.record since you set it only there, while for getPicklistValues I'm going to use settlementStatus which is not used in your code.
export default class RegistryTransferPath extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @api recordId;
    stageOptions;
    settlementStatus;
    @track record;
    @track acceptance;

    currentStep = "slds-path__item slds-is-current";
    completeStep = "slds-path__item slds-is-active";
    incompleteStep = "slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete";

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRT({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(
                "registryTransferPath @wire getRecord recordId: ",
                this.recordId
            );
            this.record = data;
            this.acceptance = getFieldValue(this.record, ISSUE_CONTRACT_ACCEPTANCE);
            this.error = undefined;
            console.log("@wire this.acceptance: " + this.acceptance);
            this.initializeStageOptions();
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            console.log("error: " + error);
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: REGISTRY_TRANSFER })
    registryTransfer;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$registryTransfer.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: REGISTRY_TRANSFER_SETTLEMENT_STATUS
    })
    picklistValues({ data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.settlementStatus = data;
            this.initializeStageOptions();
        }
    }
    
    initializeStageOptions() {
        if (!this.record || !this.settlementStatus) {
            return;
        }
        
        let increment = 1;
        console.log("getPicklistValues this.acceptance: " + this.acceptance);
        const isAcceptanceEnabled = this.acceptance === "Enabled" || !this.acceptance;
        console.log("isAcceptanceEnabled: " + isAcceptanceEnabled);
        this.stageOptions = this.settlementStatus.values
            .filter(
                (item) =>
                    isAcceptanceEnabled ||
                    (item.value !== "Awaiting Approval" &&
                     item.value !== "Contract Acceptance")
            )
            .map((item) => {
                return {
                    position: increment++,
                    value: item.value,
                    pathStatus: this.incompleteStep,
                    tickIcon: false
                };
            });
    }
}

This way both getRecord and getPicklistValues will keep running in parallel and only once both end this.stageOptions will be set.

Brilliant - solved my problem. Grazie mille!
